# AVAudioPlayer not playing audio correctly the first time

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I am working on a project that has to play audio that the user recorded themselves. When the app is launched for the first time and the user records a bit of audio, when trying to play it back, the AVAudioPlayer seems to play but is immediately stopped. If the user try to record another bit of audio, the AVAudioPlayer works fine.

Code for playing and stopping audio:

```
@objc func playAudio() {
    if audioPlayer == nil {
        do{
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filename.path) {
                print("File Exists")
            }
            else {
                print("File Doesnt Exists")
            }

            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: filename)
            audioPlayer.delegate = self
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
            print(audioPlayer.isPlaying)
            print("Playing Audio")
            playStopButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Stop Button"), for: .normal)
        }catch {
            //displayAlert(title: "Oops!", message: "There was an error. Try Recording Again")
            print(error)
        }
    }
    else {
        playStopButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Play Button"), for: .normal)
        audioPlayer.stop()
        audioPlayer = nil
    }
}

func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    if flag {
        print("Stopping Cuase Comlete")
        playStopButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Play Button"), for: .normal)
        audioPlayer.stop()
        audioPlayer = nil
    }
}
```

Code For Recording Audio

```
@objc func record() {

    if audioRecorder == nil{

        let settings = [AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC), AVSampleRateKey: 12000, AVNumberOfChannelsKey:1, AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue]

        do{
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: filename, settings: settings)
            audioRecorder.delegate = self
            audioRecorder.record()
            //view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            //recordButton.setTitle("Stop Recording", for: .normal)
            setupTimer()
            timerDisplay.isHidden = false
            shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        }catch{
            displayAlert(title: "Oops!", message: "Recording Failed")
        }
    }
    else{
        audioRecorder.stop()
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
        audioRecorder=nil;

        timerDisplay.isHidden = true
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        let selected = arr[picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        UserDefaults.standard.set(selected, forKey: "SelectedTopic")

        present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: PlaybackController()), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: check path provided for first time is correct ?

Comment: @iOSGeek yes it returns true that the file exists every time

Comment: I do not see any mistake It can happen just because of filename if provided incorrectly , as second Time Its working fine , hard to catch error

Comment: @iOSGeek It can’t be the file name the file name is the same each time

Comment: I am facing same issue, Have you find any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getting same issue with audiorecorder.I fixed by making a method to setup a player. like this:

```
func setupView() {
        recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        do {
            try recordingSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
            try recordingSession.setActive(true)
            recordingSession.requestRecordPermission() { [unowned self] allowed in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if allowed {
                        self.loadRecordingUI()
                    } else {
                        // failed to record
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            // failed to record
        }
    }
```

and then calling it in my viewDidLoad.as:

```
self.setupView()
```